# Read SOAP message response ASP.NET MVC4 C#

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, soap, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a remotely hosted XML SOAP message which I need to read within my ASP.NET MVC C# web application. I am new to ALL of the above technologies so please go easy on me.

1. How do I connect to the data source
2. How do I create a model to model the SOAP message
3. What is the LinQ query I would need to turn get the contents of "GetMetalQuoteResult" into a C# object? e.g. Gain access to the individual elements of the soap message response.

Schema below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <soap:Body>
        <GetMetalQuoteResponse xmlns="http://.../...">
            <GetMetalQuoteResult>
                <Type>string</Type>
                <Currency>string</Currency>
                <Date>Date</Date>
                <Time>Time</Time>
                <Rate>decimal</Rate>
                <Bid>decimal</Bid>
                <BidTime>Time</BidTime>
                <ExpTime>DateTime</ExpTime>
                <DisplayTime>Time</DisplayTime>
                <DisplayDate>Date</DisplayDate>
                <Ask>Decimal</Ask>
                <AskTime>Time</AskTime>
            </GetMetalQuoteResult>
        </GetMetalQuoteResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

At present, I have the following code within my controller.

```
var xml = XElement.Load(url);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("");
foreach (XElement x in xml.Nodes())
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(x.Name + ":\n"+ x.Value);
}
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("");
```

But this just returns the following:

```
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}
Body:XAUGBP5/22/201212:21:04 PM1000.86251000.862512:21:04 PM2012 May 22 12:21 PM BST1:21:04 PM EDT05/22/121001.249412:21:04 PM
```

I need it to return on a separate line:

```
Type: XAU
Currency: GBP
Date: 5/22/201212:21:04
....
....
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

A good option might be to generate a client proxy class.  You can do this either by adding a service reference within Visual Studio, or by using the [wsdl.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6.aspx) command line tool.  That way you can invoke the method and receive the result as a regular C# object, without having to worry too much about the SOAP infrastructure.

Once you have the client proxy, you can write code that looks something like this:

```
var client = new ServiceReference.ServiceClient();
var result = client.GetMetalQuote();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(result.GetMetalQuoteResult.Currency);
// etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get the results:

```
var result = root1.Descendants()
     .First(x => x.Name.LocalName == "GetMetalQuoteResult")
     .Elements()
     .Select(x => new { Name = x.Name.LocalName, Value = x.Value })
     .ToArray();
```

To get the result values:

```
foreach(var x in result)
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(x.Name + ": "+ x.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        string url = "http://www..../...";
        var xml = XElement.Load(url);
        XNamespace ns = "http://.../...";
        var results =
            from result in xml.Descendants(ns + "GetMetalQuoteResult")
            select new SpotPriceModel
            {
                Type = result.Element(ns + "Type").Value,
                Currency = result.Element(ns + "Currency").Value,
                ...
                ...
                Ask = (decimal)result.Element(ns + "Ask"),
                AskTime = result.Element(ns + "AskTime").Value
            };

        var spot = results.First();

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\n\nASK:\t" + spot.Ask + "\n\n");

        return View(spot);
    }
```

Comment: While this post may answer the question, it is still a good idea to add some explanation and, possibly, some links to the relevant documentation. Answers with good explanations and references are usually more useful both to the current OP and to the future visitors. Full detailed answers are also more likely to attract positive votes.